# is it possible to use ORDER BY column not in the GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

like the title said, here is my code:

```
SELECT
  material,
  SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount],
  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8)
FROM
  [rec_stats]
GROUP BY
  material,
  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8)
ORDER BY
  material,date_in
```

the code wont run because of the date_in, is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Apply another aggregate, so how about;

```
order by min([date_in])
```

Answer (score 2):

Order by the same expression you're grouping by.

It is better to group and order on the `DATE` representation of the month.

In `SQL Server 2008` that would be:

```
SELECT  material, SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount], DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
FROM    [rec_stats]
GROUP BY
        material,
        DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
ORDER BY
        material, DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: but that would cause it to order it alphabetically because it has been converted into varchar, i need it to be ordered by the date...

Comment: @dreamer: that's the beauty of yyyy-mm-dd format; lexical ordering is chronological ordering. :)

Answer (score 1):

**use this**

> ```
> order by
> 1,2,3,4,5
> ```

Comment: this works but mind explaining how?

Comment: This doesn't account for any dynamic listing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only order by what is possible to use in a select statement.  Date_in by itself is not possible in the selection statement so you can't use it.  Depending on your RDBMS you can do the following:

```
SELECT
material,
  SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount],
  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8)
FROM
  [rec_stats]
GROUP BY
  material,
  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8)
ORDER BY
  material,RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8)
```

Comment: but that would cause it to order it alphabetically because it has been converted into varchar, i need it to be ordered by the date...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to aggregate by month?  If so, try:

```
SELECT
  material,
  SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount],
  DATEPART(year, [date_in]) as y,
  DATEPART(month, [date_in]) as m,
  DATEPART(month, [date_in]) + ' ' + DATEPART(year, [date_in]) AS MonthYearCombined
FROM
  [rec_stats]
GROUP BY
  material,
  DATEPART(year, [date_in]),
  DATEPART(month, [date_in])
ORDER BY
  material,y,m
```

Note: You may have to convert the values in the "MonthYearCombined" column - I would actually recommend you do that in code rather than SQL, but wanted to include some reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deal with the date_in column like your original query. Rather, you can NEST the query and read it like this:

```
SELECT
  material,
  SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount],
  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8)
FROM
(
Select material, Amount, RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(50), [date_in], 106), 8) as DateIn
From [rec_stats]
) X
GROUP BY
  material,
  DateIn
ORDER BY
  material,DateIn
```

I cannot test it in my dev environment but I believe this gives you the idea.