# Ordering Postgresql Table Results by Chronological Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following Postgresql query:

```
SELECT 
    to_char("Date", 'Mon') AS mon,
    extract(year from "Date") AS yyyy,
    SUM("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E0%') AS HTT,
    SUM("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E1%') AS TTT
FROM 
    "Transactions"
WHERE 
    "Date" BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '08/31/2015'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 
    yyyy, 
    mon;
```

The results I get are in following order:

```
Mon | yyyy | HTT | TTT |
Apr | 2014 | 50  | 75  |
Aug | 2014 | 60  | 80  |
Dec | 2014 | 55  | 40  |
Jul | 2014 | 60  | 45  |
Jun | 2014 | 50  | 55  |
```

However, I would like to be able to get the results in chronological date order by month and year, so that the results are displayed like this:

```
Mon | yyyy | HTT | TTT |
Apr | 2014 | 50  | 75  |
Jun | 2014 | 50  | 55  |
Jul | 2014 | 60  | 45  |
Aug | 2014 | 60  | 80  |
Dec | 2014 | 55  | 40  |
```

Is there a way to query in such a way so that the Mon and yyyy are displayed in chronological mon and year order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `group by`, so the easiest way is to order by a date in each group:

```
order by min("Date")
```

Comment: Why ordering by `MIN()` ?

Comment: @fpietka . . . It chooses one date from the time period and uses that for ordering.  `max("Date")` could also be used.  Any idea why the downvote?

Comment: Ok, it avoids `GROUP BY` requirement on `Date` that way, using an aggregate function on the date. Didn't know it would be valid until I saw it [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818216/is-it-possible-to-use-order-by-column-not-in-the-group-by). It should be said since it is an important part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table (subquery) with an additional column for `year-month`:

```
select mon, yyyy, HTT, TTT
from (
    select 
        to_char("Date", 'YYYYMM') as year_month,
        to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
        extract(year from "Date") as yyyy,
        sum("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E0%') as HTT,
        sum("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E1%') as TTT
    from "Transactions"
    where "Date" between '01/01/2015' and '08/31/2015'
    group by 1,2,3
    ) sub
order by year_month;
```

or truncate `"Date"` to month in a subquery:

```
select 
    to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
    extract(year from "Date") as yyyy,
    sum("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E0%') as HTT,
    sum("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E1%') as TTT
from (
    select date_trunc('month', "Date") "Date", "Amount", "Type"
    from "Transactions"
    where "Date" between '01/01/2015' and '08/31/2015'
    ) sub
group by "Date"
order by "Date";
```